# Show a message if user is not logged in

Tags: php, php-parse-error

My home page has an link to the profile page (profile.php). The profile page can only be seen by the users who are logged in. If a user clicks the profile link before log in he/she will be redirected to the login page (login.php) and a message (`$mssg`) will appear on the top of the log in form. **--- this is what I want.**

**What is wrong in my observation:**  The header function can't seem to get the `$mssg` along with the page location.

**profile.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['valid'])){
$_SESSION['intruder']="stranger";
header('Location: login.php?$mssg=" You are not logged in. Please log in to see the profile. "');
}
?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['intruder'])) //print nothing
else {
  echo $mssg;
}
// log in form code, email, password etc.
?>
```

**The error I'm geting:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sss\login.php on line 4

Why is it not working? Do you think my code is wrong? If so, then how can I fix it or get what I want?

Comment: I'm sorry? ... I did not understand what you are trying to say. @Pitchinnate

Comment: Lol sorry it was a joke because you typed massage, not message.

Comment: @user3017315 A massage is not a message. In English, a [massage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/massage) is amusingly quite different.

Comment: :D ....  good one! silly spelling mistake!

Comment: you should definitely see this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzbgpGuX6-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors:

```
$mssg = urlencode('Your message here');
header('Location: login.php?mssg=' . $mssg);
```

Then:

```
echo $_GET['mssg'];
```

Comment: I'd also reccomend to use [urlencode](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: @JanTuroň yeah that is a good idea to make sure the GET variable doesn't get altered.

Answer (score 2):

Add an empty block after your `if`:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['intruder'])) //print nothing
{ ; }
else {
  echo $mssg;
}
```

or just do this:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['intruder'])){
  echo $mssg;
}
```

Comment: **Now I'm getting this:** Notice: Undefined variable: mssg in C:\xampp\htdocs\sss\login.php on line 5

Comment: Seems like you have another error, did you have code like $mssg = $_GET['mssg'] to get the parameter on the url?

Comment: I tried both of them. but both of them gives me the notice (given in the previous comment)

Comment: Combine our answers, then you should be able to make it work!